# In Spring 5 JMS docmentation of DefaultMessageListenerContainer clarification of Destination wanted

Tags: spring, jms

```
<!-- this is the Message Driven POJO (MDP) -->
<bean id="messageListener" class="jmsexample.ExampleListener"/>

<!-- and this is the message listener container -->
<bean id="jmsContainer"    
class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
<property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
<property name="destination" ref="destination"/>
<property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener"/>
</bean>
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#jms

How do you define the bean ref'destination' in  property name="destination" ref="destination"

Comment: The definition of messageListener is present but not destination.  I have tried in vain to resolve.

Comment: We are using AWS SQS